# Different results in IntelliJ scala worksheet and console

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, worksheet, json4s

I'm trying to parse jsons with following code:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

import org.json4s._
import org.json4s.ext.EnumNameSerializer
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

object Area extends Enumeration {
  type Area = Value
  val grid, stream = Value
}
implicit val formats = new DefaultFormats {
  override def dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
} + new EnumNameSerializer(Area)
case class EventJsonInput(ids: Array[String]
                          , cluster: Int
                          , operation: String
                          , area: Area.Area
                          , position: Option[Int]
                          )

parse("""{"ids":["1"],"operation": "update","cluster": 3,
    "area": "grid"} """).extractOpt[EventJsonInput]
```

When I run it via sbt -> console i get following result:

```
res0: Option[EventJsonInput] = Some(EventJsonInput([Ljava.lang.String;@29f999f,3,update,grid,None))
```

When I run it via interactive mode in worksheet the result is:

```
res0: Option[EventJsonInput] = None
```

I have no idea why :( I tried to make everythin Optional, but it didn't help.

- I'm using: IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.1
- Build: #IC-143.382
- JRE: 1.7.0_79-b14amd64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation

sbt -> about:

```
[info] This is sbt 0.13.8
[info] The current project is {file:/home/user/.../}... 0.025-SNAPSHOT
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.10.5
[info] Available Plugins: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin, sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin, sbt.plugins.CorePlugin, sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin, sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin, sbtdocker.DockerPlugin, sbtrelease.ReleasePlugin
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
```

Comment: What version of json4s do you use? I don't find the parse-method

Comment: I'm using json4s version 3.2.10. You can find `parse` in the examples [here](http://json4s.org/).